# why strtotime showing only one string?

Tags: php

I have an API which return start time and end time like 
1899-12-30T16:30:00

I am trying to convert above string into time but using `echo  date('H:i:s', strtotime($starttime))` where $starttime is returning from API.
 and above string is returning 17:00:00 but if I echo only $starttime it is showing  1899-12-30T16:30:00

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: It echoes `16:30:00` for me.

Comment: @haim770 I am using 5.2.17

Comment: @haim770 is there any other way ...it is not showing currect value at my end

Comment: Run `date_default_timezone_get()` to check your current timezone. Maybe you're in a +0:30 timezone.

Comment: @haim770 Why should the timezone matter? The string doesn't have a timezone in it, so it will be interpreted in the default timezone.

Comment: @haim770 endtime is different from start time but value of both is showing 17:00:00

Comment: @Barmar, see http://3v4l.org/neMXn#v510

Comment: @haim770 if I don't set timezone why end and start showing same time http://3v4l.org/HllHi#v510

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with timezone, it's more a precision problem related to dates prior to 1900. See http://3v4l.org/LsMI5

Comment: Use DateTime objects if you want to work with dates outside the 32 bit signed integer range

Comment: @mark baker could u please give an example how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) if you want to work with dates outside the 32-bit signed integer range

```
$starttime = "1899-12-30T16:30:00";
$dateTimeObject = new DateTime($starttime);
echo $dateTimeObject->format('H:i:s');
```

or

```
$starttime = "1899-12-30T16:30:00";
$dateTimeObject = new DateTime($starttime, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $dateTimeObject->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to set the timezone in the php settings or in the specific php page,

when I try to run it:

```
$starttime = "1899-12-30T16:30:00";
echo  date('H:i:s', strtotime($starttime));
```

I got

```
16:30:00
```

Comment: Since the same timezone is used by both `strtotime` and `date`, why would it matter what timezone is set?

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit version of PHP?